# InaccessibleObjectException when running tests

Tags: java, junit

I created the first test for a project as below:

```
package my.module.sub;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class FirstTest {

  @Test
  void firstTest() {
    System.out.println("Tests are now running");
  }

}
```

But when I run the tests I get the below error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make void my.module.sub.FirstTest.firstTest() accessible: module my.module does not "opens my.module.sub" to unnamed module @7dc0f706
```

It seems that if I add `opens my.module.sub` to the `module-info.java` file the test will run fine.

Obviously I would rather that not be there. So what is the best way to prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Well I think it's different because in that question the person knows that it should be public. For me I started out not knowing that or why my tests are not running. Only in the answer do I state that it turned out to be the reason. In essence one question is asking "why should they be public" and my question is asking "why aren't they running" where the answer is "they should be public".

Comment: @user7294900 In JUnit 5, default access is sufficient for a test method, and it is not related to the exception, which has to do with the Java module system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be because `firstTest()` was not public. So when running the tests, JUnit was not able to access the method.

In the end all I had to do to fix the issue was change `firstTest()` to:

```
public void firstTest()
```

Comment: That should be unnecessary with JUnit 5. Default access should be sufficient, it seems more like the Java module system is interfering here.

Comment: This helped me as well. Also, I had to make the test class itself public + the method annotated with @BeforeEach annotation. Otherwise I was receiving the same error. By the way, I have some api packages which are open in my module-info.java. Tests for classes in those packages are not failing when using the default access to the test methods which are supported by JUnit 5.